# How to calculate average sensitivity and specificity at specified cutoff in ROCR package?

Tags: r, roc

I use `ROCR` package to draw the ROC curve. The code is as follows:

```
pred <- prediction(my.pred, my.label)
perf <- performance(my.pred, 'tpr', 'fpr')
plot(perf,avg="threshold")
```

My `pred` and `perf` object is not a vector but a list, so I can get an average ROC curve.
Can anyone tell me how to calculate average sensitivity and  specificity at a specified cutoff in `ROCR` package?

Comment: This approach is completely at odds with making optimum decisions, which use predicted risks and utility functions.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, `ROCR` is an overkill for this task. The `performance` function of `ROCR` returns performance metrics at every score that is present in its input. So, theoretically you could do the following:

```
library(ROCR)
set.seed(123)
N <- 1000
POSITIVE_CASE <- 'case A'
NEGATIVE_CASE <- 'case B'
CUTOFF <- 0.456

scores <- rnorm(n=N)
labels <- ifelse(runif(N) > 0.5, POSITIVE_CASE, NEGATIVE_CASE)



pred <- prediction(scores, labels)
perf <- performance(pred, 'sens', 'spec')
```

At this point `perf` contains a lot of useful information:

```
  > str(perf)
  Formal class 'performance' [package "ROCR"] with 6 slots
  ..@ x.name      : chr "Specificity"
  ..@ y.name      : chr "Sensitivity"
  ..@ alpha.name  : chr "Cutoff"
  ..@ x.values    :List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:1001] 1 1 0.998 0.996 0.996 ...
  ..@ y.values    :List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:1001] 0 0.00202 0.00202 0.00202 0.00405 ...
  ..@ alpha.values:List of 1
  .. ..$ : num [1:1001] Inf 3.24 2.69 2.68 2.58 ...
```

Now you can search for your score cut-off in `perf@alpha.values` and find the corresponding sensitivity and specificity values. If you don't find the exact cut-off value in `perf@alpha.values`, you'll have to do some interpolation:

```
ix <- which.min(abs(perf@alpha.values[[1]] - CUTOFF)) #good enough in our case
sensitivity <- perf@y.values[[1]][ix] #note the order of arguments to `perfomance` and of x and y in `perf`
specificity <- perf@x.values[[1]][ix]
```

Which gives you:

```
> sensitivity
[1] 0.3319838
> specificity
[1] 0.6956522
```

**But** there is a much simpler and faster way: just convert your label string to a binary vector and calculate the metrics directly:

```
binary.labels <- labels == POSITIVE_CASE
tp <- sum( (scores > threshold) & binary.labels )
sensitivity <- tp / sum(binary.labels)
tn <- sum( (scores <= threshold) & (! binary.labels))
specificity <- tn / sum(!binary.labels)
```

Which gives you:

```
> sensitivity
[1] 0.3319838
> specificity
[1] 0.6956522
```